# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't detect my second monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hardware

I'm on a new install of Ubuntu 14.04 and I have nvidia drivers.

When I go to **Settings > Display** I can only see one monitor.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution : I just used an adapter VGA to DVI between my second monitor and my computer and it's ok now.